# How to bind WPF combobox selected item with a Value Converter to a DataGridTextColumn? Both DataGridTextColumn and combobox are datagrid columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I want to bind `SelectedItem` of the combo box with a value converter to `DataGridTextColumn` after it. I am using MVVM pattern.

```
<Datagrid>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Left">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Name="Leftcombo"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Right"
                        Binding="{Binding SelectedColumn, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please note: `SelectedColumn` is a property in the ViewModel bound to `SelectedItem` of the combo box.

Binding works the way it is in XAML above, but I want to use a value converter on the `DataGridTextColumn Header="Right"` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's stopping you from using `IValueConverter`. Declare under Resource section and use it like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <namespace:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
.....
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Right"
                    Binding="{Binding SelectedColumn, Mode=OneWay, 
                                      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                      Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```